# Pdb and Python's core module loading when set_trace() is called: possible?

Tags: python, pdb

Recently I find myself using `PDB` a lot more than usual. I have my *beautiful* shortcut that quickly adds `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` where I need in my code. Now, everytime I'm in pdb, I want the emulated interactive console found in [Python's code module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html), to avoid using only oneliners while debugging.

This requires typing `!import code; code.interact(local=vars())` every time and it's utterly annoying, since I have to keep it ready for copy-and-paste or type it manually.

Is there a way to have it loaded every time `set_trace()` is called? Thanks all

Comment: Doesn't it load the local namespace when you set the trace? Or am I missing something here :O

Comment: I need it to have the emulated python interpreter console with multiline support. Living only on oneline in pdb is not healthy :(

Comment: Ah yes! I figured I did not entirely understand what was happening.

Comment: Every time? It's very rare that I need anything but oneliners when I debug. Especially now with dict and set comprehensions.

Comment: @LennartRegebro good for you.

Comment: Well, debugging is about introspection. Do you need to write functions or classes when debugging? Sure, it happens, but every time?

Comment: Since, apparently, for you that is the cardinal point of my question, I edited it. It's not that every time I *need* that kind of complexity. I just *want* it, and since I could not find anything about it on the web, I asked here. Better now?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `import code; code.interact(local=vars())` instead of `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`?